# Regex match a string and its surrounding 2 characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a particular word and then retrieve a string containing it along with its 2 neighbours on both sides

The below code achieves this partially. But it fails when the match-word appears in the beginning of the string.

So is there a more efficient, flexible way to achieve this in regex?

```
text = "The world is a small place, we should try to take care of it"
sub = r'(\w+|.)\W(\w+|.)\W+(try)\W+(\w+|.)\W'
surrounding_text = re.findall(sub, text)
```

Comment: Please provide example inputs and outputs.

Comment: You can make the sections/match-groups optional or you can use lookahead/lookbehind. upto you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?` quantifier

To match the word "try" and one character of the previous or next word:

[Try it out](https://regex101.com/r/obGJ17/2/)

`(. )?try( .)?`

Explanation:

- `(. )?`: Matches one character and then a space zero or one times
- `try`: Literally matches "try"
- `( .)?`: Matches a space and one character zero or one times

You could modify the `.` to match `\w` or `\w+` if you want to match a word character or an entire word. [Try it out](https://regex101.com/r/obGJ17/3)

To match *up to two* words on either side, you can replace the `?` with `{0, 2}` [like so](https://regex101.com/r/obGJ17/4)

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question - disregard

Answer (score 0):

You can make groups optional and use anchors:

```
(?:^|(?:(\w+)\W+)?(\w+)\W+)(world)(?:\W+(\w+)|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG5cag/2)

- `(?:^|(?:(\w+)\W+)?(\w+)\W+)`: Match line start or patter after `|`
- `(?:(\w+)\W+)?(\w+)\W+`: Match one word or two words
- `(?:\W+(\w+)|$)` matches a word after 1+ non-word chars or end of string

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = "The world is a small place, we should try to take care of it"
sub = re.compile(r'(?P<all>(\w*)\s*try\s*(\w*))')

    rez = [m.groupdict() for m in sub.finditer(text)]
    for item in rez:
       print(item["all"])
    
    text = "try to take care of it"
    
    rez = [m.groupdict() for m in sub.finditer(text)]
    for item in rez:
       print(item["all"])
```

I tested it on:

```
The world is a small place, we should try to take care of it
try to take care of it
```

and got:

```
should try to

try to
```

https://regex101.com/r/DlSJsJ/1

Comment: Just figured that that \s*try might match "\n" .. so you will want to use [ \t]* instead

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple list:

```
text = "The world is a small place, we should try to take care of it"
d = text.split()

try:
    idx = d.index('world')
    print("{} {} {}".format(d[idx - 1], d[idx], d[idx + 1]))
except ValueError:
    print("Not in the text.")
```

Which yields

```
The world is
```

You need to account for negative indices here.